# How to preview Unreal Engine 4 Project on Oculus Go

Tags: virtual, virtual-reality, unreal-engine4, blueprint, oculusgo

I started UE4 and Oculus Go development 2 days ago. I saw youtube videos where the people were able to instantly connect the device to UE4.

I followed full documentation. Turned on developer mode, Installed Android SDK, enabled the plugin and every small step in the docs.

Now when I connect Oculus go via USB it is shown in Launch options with the name '**Pacific(something)**' and I deployed the starter VR project on but nothing was moving. How to control it on Oculus?

Second thing, the VR preview remains **grayed out** no matter what I do.

UE4 version - 4.20.3

Machine - Windows (i5, 8GB)

Thanks.